# Win32 scroll-able container

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a button in C++ using Win32 API the following way:

```
HWND button = CreateWindowEx
(
    0,
    _TEXT( "BUTTON" ),
    title.c_str(),
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_SOLID,
    10, 10, 100, 100,
    parent,
    NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong( parent, GWLP_HINSTANCE ),
    NULL
);
```

I would like to be able to add 50 buttons on the form as rows, but the problem is I need a way how to scroll them. Is there a container control in which I could add these buttons and have a scrollbar functionality or is there another way how to achieve this? [image]

Comment: There is no container control. You have to add `WS_VSCROLL` style to your overlapped window and process its messages. It is not easy like on WinForm with containers. The scrollbar can be also used as separate control.

Comment: @i486 thanks! Can you please tell me what do you mean by "overlapped window" is that type of control? Thanks!

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` usually is the style of the main window of application. You can add `WS_VSCROLL` style to the main window and it will have vertical scroll bar. Then add the buttons as child windows. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-scroll-bars

Comment: PS: You have to process several messages as `WM_SIZE`, `WM_VSCROLL`, `WM_HSCROLL`, etc. to rearrange the positions of buttons and scroll the window contents. See this or other example in CodeProject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1042516/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Scrolling

Comment: There is a Container control : the Pager Control . Quick test => [Pager Control](https://i.ibb.co/HxJZT91/Pager-Control.gif) .  But it is better now to embed WPF controls like ScrollViewer